# jQuery Color Picker plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I installed jQuery plugin Color picker and I don't know how to get selected color so I can change color of my div. I followed instructions in documentation of plugin but with no luck. This is my code:

```
<div id="colorpickerHolder"></div>
<div id="colorContainer">Test</div>
```

ColorpickerHolder is div which I use to attach color picker and I made the second div just to test color picker. And in javascript file I have this:

```
$('#colorpickerHolder').ColorPicker({
    color: '#0000ff',
    onShow: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
        return false;
    },
    onHide: function (colpkr) {
        $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
        return false;
    },
    onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
        $('#colorContainer').css('color', '#' + hex);
    }
});
```

I included all .js files which I found in plugin folder so I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Is the "ColorPicker" library hosted somewhere so that we can reference it or include it in a jsFiddle?

Comment: http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/ This is the plugin I use

Comment: I linked to the files at eyecon's example page. Seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/mshZ2/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#colorpickerHolder').ColorPicker({
        color: '#0000ff',
        onShow: function (colpkr) {
            $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
            return false;
        },
        onHide: function (colpkr) {
            $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
            return false;
        },
        onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
            $('#colorContainer').css('color', '#' + hex);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Some explanation would be helpful.

Comment: Just pasting code makes everyone else have to figure out what your answer actually is. Here's the explanation: This answer wraps your ColorPicker code inside a jQuery function that executes when the document is ready. This ensures that required assets are loaded before running ColorPicker. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @Alen I don't see that in the code you provided. You may want to edit your question and provide *all relevant code*.

Comment: Here is a working example using this answer's method: http://jsfiddle.net/mshZ2/1/

Comment: @showdev Your fiddle helped me, it seems I had some typo, I don't know, I copied your code and it works. Thank you